# JavaFX MediaPlayer does not play mp3 with large png cover

Tags: java, javafx, media

I am not able to play mp3 that contains large png file as a cover (thumbnail) image using javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer class. You can find in attached archive example mp3 files and NetBeans project with compiled application that you can use to reproduce my issue. As I try opening mp3, MediaPlayer does not throw any exceptions, however the file is not played.

Mp3 file without cover is playing ok and if I include in mp3 the same cover but in jpg format it is also playing fine. I can play mp3 with large png cover using MPC-HC x64 and with standard Windows Media Player. I tested this on Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit, using Java 8 Update 25, build 1.8.0_25-b18.

In my scenario changing mp3 file itself is not feasible. I would greatly appreciate any hint towards workaround that does not involve changing contents of mp3 file.

You can find the mentioned archive here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1vzw6hqteza0164/BugReproduction.zip?dl=0

P.S. you can change mp3 cover image with mp3tag application (http://www.mp3tag.de/en/download.html).

Comment: Log a bug report at in the JavaFX issue tracker at: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test your code and according to you the problem is the dimension of cover image also jpg not only png if image is over 2MB ... so according to @jewelsea you can Log a bug report at javafx-jira.kenai.com,

I can suggest to you one code solution :
You can create with java code a temp file of mp3 that don't have image cover ...

```
...
mediaPlayer.setOnError(()-> {
  (code to create temp file ...)
  Media media = new Media(<tempfile>);
  mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
  mediaPlayer.play();
});
mediaPlayer.play();
```

For this there are two solutions:

1) You can study the structure of mp3 file in [this](http://www.multiweb.cz/twoinches/mp3inside.htm#MP3FileStructure) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3) on wikipedia

2) You can install eyeD3 for windows, see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5T2fJCiVUVw) and use from java code this options from line command  `eyeD3 --remove-image mp3file tempmp3file` for create temp file, read [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/eyeD3.1.html)

Comment: I hope essert helpful

Comment: Thanks! I logged a bug report.